# Client certificate authorization fails with .net but works with Postman

Tags: .net, ssl-certificate, certificate, client-certificates

I have been provided with a pfx and pem client certificates for authenticating a certain server and the task is to send a POST request with either of these certificate. The application which needs to use these certificates to make a call is a .net core webapi. I had tried multiple ways to add this client certificate in the http client before making the call but each time I get 401 Unauthorized. I have tried the RestSharp as well but no luck. But the interesting thing is that this works seamlessly with Postman. Could someone please help in this. Below is the Named HttpClient registration and the request code that I am currently using per Microsoft documentation.

At Startup:

```
var clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Dir\Client.pfx", "Password");

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("namedClient", c =>
{
}).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);
    handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
    handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    handler.PreAuthenticate = true;
    handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
    return handler;
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
...
```

At business logic :

```
var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("namedClient");
var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
{
   RequestUri = new Uri("https://www.test.com/resource1"),
   Method = HttpMethod.Post,
};
request.Headers.Host = "www.test.com";
var response = client.SendAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: Have you ever found the cause of this? We have the same problem. What's interesting: the same code works fine for some users, but does not work for other users. Same behavior on several machines (some users can make the call, some cannot).

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue. Works via curl and postman call, but doesn't work in the code.
Try to switch `HttpClientHandler` on `SocketsHttpHandler`:

```
var handler = new SocketsHttpHandler();
handler.SslOptions = new SslClientAuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection { clientCertificate }
};
```

Even though `HttpClientHandler` is based on `SocketsHttpHandler`. | link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=net-6.0#httpclienthandler-in-net-core)
The behavior of these handlers is different.

Comment: This answer should be the correct answer. It help me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem, ie. Postman or a Python script could call the remote API using the client certificate without issues, while our c# program could not.

What finally helped: we imported the .pfx into "Intermediate Certification Authorities" store (under the user who will be calling the c# program). After that the c# program works fine too.